# Url encoding quotes and spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, urlencode

I have some query text that is being encoded with JavaScript, but I've encountered a use case where I might have to encode the same text on the server side, and the encoding that's happening is not the same. I need it to be the same. Here's an example.

I enter `"I like food"` into the search box and hit the `search` button. JavaScript encodes this as `%22I%20like%20food%22`

Let's say I get the same value as a string on a request object on the server side. It will look like this: `"\"I like food\""`

When I use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)`, the result is `"%22I+like+food%22"`. If I use `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(value)`, the result is `"\"I%20like%20food\""`

So `UrlEncode` is encoding my quotes but is using the `+` character for spaces. `UrlPathEncode` is encoding my spaces but is not encoding my escaped quotes.

I really need it to do both, otherwise the Search code completely borks on me (and I have no control over the search code).

Tips?

Comment: Do a string search/replace to replace spaces with %20's, then do the regular UrlEncode?

Comment: @Marc B: Wouldn't that make UrlEncode encode the "%" characters (resulting in %2520 for each space)? Very strange behaviour of UrlPathEncode. At least UrlEncode documents its conversion from spaces to "+". UrlPathEncode sais nothing about not converting quotes...

Comment: Hmm. good point. I guess you could go the other way, UrlEncode first, then search/replace +'s with %20's

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, the solution from Marc B is not completely correct, as if the root string contains "+" char, this will convert it to a space. The only solution I see is to convert first spaces to a string like "THIS_IS_A_SPACE" and then use UrlEncode, and then convert "THIS_IS_A_SPACE" to %20

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`UrlPathEncode` doesn't escape `"` because they don't need to be escaped in path components.

[`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Strange that very few people know about this.

Comment: I agree. Wish that the use/knowledge of Uri.EscapeDataPath was more widespread, as this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few options available to you, the fastest might be to use UrlEncode then do a string.replace to swap the `+` characters with `%20`.

Something like

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(input).Replace("+", "%20");
```

Comment: Thanks. I considered the string replacement option, but I was hoping there would be a method that would actually work correctly. Looks like I will have to fall back on this though. Of course, you said there are a few options and you only listed one... I'd be interested to see the others. Thanks!

Comment: I found useful System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(string str); to  give %20 for space

Comment: I don't like this solution at all.. replacing "+" with "%20" will solve problems if text has spaces in it, but will create other problems if text has "+"  !!!

Comment: @EmanueleGreco If you've already url encoded the string, then it will not contain any + characters that aren't supposed to be spaces. The + symbol will be encoded to %2B.

Answer (score -1):

```
WebUtility.UrlEncode(str)
```

Will encode all characters that need encoded using the `%XX` format, including space.

Comment: This is just plain wrong and therefore misleading. `WebUtility.UrlEncode` turns a space into a '+'

Comment: Note: this answer was flagged, and subsequently went into a [review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16071767). It shouldn't have been flagged as it's an attempt to answer the question. The response to wrong answers is to downvote, not flag.