# C# string format error

Tags: c#

I need to send the value I receive from the model with this link, the proposalName field must be in quotes.How can I do it?

Here is my service url.

```
   string path = string.Format("{ProposalId:{proposalId},ProposalName:{"proposalName"},VendorId:{vendorId}}",
               Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalId.ToString()),
               Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalName),
               Uri.EscapeDataString(vendorId.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply put quotes around by escaping the quotes, like this -

```
string path = string.Format("{{0},ProposalName:\"{1}\",VendorId:{2}}",
                   Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalId.ToString()),
                   Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalName),
                   Uri.EscapeDataString(vendorId.ToString()));
```

As per your updated question, if you need to pass double quotes in URL, you need to encode it to **%22**

You can also use `URI` which allows a lot of flexibility with urls. For example -

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://google.com/search?hl=en&q=\"query with quotes\"");
```

**Going with your example** - Replace `EscapeDataString` with `Uri.EscapeUriString`. It will escape the chracter to form a valid URL. `"` will get replaced by `%22`

Some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374093/double-quotation-inside-url-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010301/how-do-you-launch-a-url-that-includes-quotes)-

Comment: @ozmert75 - Edited my answer for your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem exactlly in the `{"1"}` part. The double quotation mark `"` should be outside the `{}`, not inside them.
here is the fixed code.

```
string path = string.Format("{{0},ProposalName:\"{1}\",VendorId:{2}}",
               Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalId.ToString()),
               Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalName),
               Uri.EscapeDataString(vendorId.ToString()));
```

or

```
string path = string.Format(@"{{0},ProposalName:""{1}"",VendorId:{2}}",
               Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalId.ToString()),
               Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalName),
               Uri.EscapeDataString(vendorId.ToString()));
```

and if you are using C# 6 then you can write it as following

```
string path = $"{Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalId.ToString())},ProposalName:\"{Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalName)}\",VendorId:{Uri.EscapeDataString(vendorId.ToString())}";
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
\"{1}\"
```

instead of

```
{"1"}
```

because you can put `\` symbol to indicate escape sequence followed by a reserved characters

So

```
string.Format("{{{0},ProposalName:\"{1}\",VendorId:{2}}}",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think escaping the quotes and placing them outside the brackets will work:

```
"{{0},ProposalName:\"{1}\",VendorId:{2}}"
```

Depending on the C# version, you can also do it like this, which I often think is an easier and cleaner way to do it:

```
 string path = $"{proposalId},ProposalName:\"{proposalName}\",VendorId:{vendorId}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have *two* problems:

- Wrong quotation (should be *outside* the braces `{...}` and *escaped*)
- Incorrect `{` and `}` escape: `{{` means just a single `'{'` in a formatting string

Should be

```
string path = string.Format("{{{0},ProposalName:\"{1}\",VendorId:{2}}}",
```

please, notice

- escaped quotations `\"` which are outside `{1}`
- tripled curly braces`{{{` and `}}}`

**Edit**: in your *edited* question you have the same errors:

```
string format = 
  "http://mobile.teklifdosyam.com/VendorReport/GetListProposalService?&page=1&start=0&limit=10&filter=" + 
   "{{ProposalId:{0},ProposalName:\"{1}\",VendorId:{2}}}";

string path = string.Format(format,
  Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalId.ToString()),
  Uri.EscapeDataString(proposalName),
  Uri.EscapeDataString(vendorId.ToString()));
```

please, notice escaped quotations `\"` which are outside the `{1}`, double `'{{'` and tripled `'}}}'`. When formatting you have to use numbers as place holders: so `{"proposalName"}` must be changed into `{0}`