# C# Outlook Mail With Quotes

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to send an email via `Outlook`. I am using this code which does work.

```
var url = "mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=Foobar [ID_01] P1&body=somerandomtext";
Process.Start(url);
```

When I replace "somerandomtext" with, let's say `TextBox1.Text` and there are double-quotes (") inside TextBox1, Outlook responses with:

*The command line argument is invalid. Check the command you are using.*

I could just do `TextBox1.Text.Replace("\"", "'")` but there has to be a way to send/autofill double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial suggestion was to use `UrlEncoding`

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7#System_Net_WebUtility_UrlEncode_System_String_)

> URL encoding replaces characters that are not allowed in a URL with character-entity equivalents consisting of hexadecimal escape sequences.

This would work fine for double quotes, but if there are spaces in the body text that would be converted to "+"

For e.g., if the string is:

```
this is for "testing"
```

Using `UrlEncode`, it would be converted to:

```
this+is+for+%22testing%22
```

[image]

The above does not look nice.

So a better solution is to replace double quote with %22 manually.

```
var changedText = body.Replace("\"", "%22");
```

This would give the output as:

[image]

The full list of replacement strings for the "mailto" handler for Outlook is available [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287573/how-to-use-command-line-switches-to-create-a-pre-addressed-e-mail-mess):

> The following variables are used to represent commonly used characters:
>
> Space ( ) %20
>
> Comma (,) %2C
>
> Question Mark (?) %3F
>
> Period (.) %2E
>
> Exclamation Point (!) %21
>
> Colon (:) %3A
>
> Semicolon (;) %3B

The MSDN page for [mailto handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710215(v=vs.85).aspx) has these additional details:

> Windows Internet Explorer 7 and later. You must percent-encode all URL-reserved characters within a mailto: address. For example, the number sign (#) is used as a fragment identifier in URLs. When processing an address such as some#one@example.com, Internet Explorer copies only the portion up to the number sign into the mail client; the fragment portion including the number sign is ignored. This behavior is by design.
>
> For more information on the mailto protocol, see [RFC2368](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt): The mailto URL scheme.

After some additional tests and googling around, it seems that there is a simpler [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820167/url-encoding-quotes-and-spaces) - use `Uri.EscapeDataString`

This [handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?view=netframework-4.7#System_Uri_EscapeDataString_System_String_) all the necessary conversions.